# Look back at previous week for data in R without loops

Tags: r, loops, date

I have data in the following format in R and I need to create a column which involves looking back the week before

| Person | Duration | Date | Type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| C | 10 | 29/1/22 | T |
| B | 14 | 1/2/22 | T |
| B | 12 | 1/2/22 | T |
| C | 34 | 1/2/22 | T |
| B | 45 | 8/2/22 | M |
| C | 11 | 8/2/22 | M |

I am looking at a way of avoiding loops as I have discovered that they take a long time in R

Essentially I want to loop through entire datatable and if the type is M look back at the previous week before the date of M. Then if there is anything involving that person to add the duration. In this example it would create the following column

| Person | Duration | Date | Type | Total Dur |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| C | 10 | 29/1/22 | T | N/A |
| B | 14 | 1/2/22 | T | N/A |
| B | 12 | 1/2/22 | T | N/A |
| C | 34 | 1/2/22 | T | N/A |
| B | 45 | 8/2/22 | M | 26 (adding rows 2 and 3 together) |
| C | 11 | 8/2/22 | M | 34 (only row 4 as row 1 is not week before) |

My first post here so hope that all makes sense

Comment: I'd do something like `library(dplyr); library(slider); df %>% group_by(Person) %>% mutate(Total_Dur = slide_index_dbl(Duration, Date, sum, .before = 7)`.  Will be easier to do math on your dates if you convert them to a Date format, which in R is in iso8601 and will display like 2022-01-29.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how generic a solution this will be given your whole dataset may have execptions, but windowed definitions of the calculated fields below should be able to deal with some potential complexity

```
library(magrittr)
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

person <- c("c", "b", "b", "c", "b", "c")
duration <- c(10, 14, 12, 34, 45, 11)
date <- c("29/1/22", "1/2/22", "1/2/22", "1/2/22", "8/2/22", "8/2/22")
type <- c("T","T","T","T","M","M")

df <- 
  data.frame(person,
           duration,
           date,
           type) %>% 
  mutate(date = dmy(date))

df %>%
  group_by(person) %>%
  mutate(
    MinDate = date[type=="M"] - days(7),
    TotalDur = if_else(type == "M", sum(duration[date >= MinDate & type != "M"]), NA_real_))
```